# Python/C Raw Socket Operations using Django, Mod_WSGI, Apache

Tags: python, django, sockets, mod-wsgi, freebsd

I'm currently writing a web application using Django, Apache, and mod_wsgi that provides some FreeBSD server management and configuration features, including common firewall operations.

My Python/C library uses raw sockets to interact directly with the firewall and works perfectly fine when running as root, but raw socket operations are only allowed for root.

At this point, the only thing I can think of is to install and use sudo to explicitly allow the www user access to /sbin/ipfw which isn't ideal since I would prefer to use my raw socket library operations rather than a subprocess call.

I suppose another option would be to write (local domain sockets) or use an existing job system (Celery?) that runs as root and handles these requests.

Or perhaps there's some WSGI Daemon mode trickery I'm unaware of? I'm sure this issue has been encountered before. Any advice on the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Use Celery or some other back end service which runs as root. Having a web application process run as root is a security problem waiting to happen. This is why mod_wsgi blocks you running daemon processes as root. Sure you could hack the code to disable the exclusion, but I am not about to tell you how to do that.

Comment: I agree and certainly don't have any intention of running apache/mod_wsgi as root..that's why I'm here. Celery seems to be a bit overkill for this one operation, but it may prove useful for other tasks in future implementations.